# CreateDispatch causes Vista to get all twitchy

Tags: com, windows-vista, automation, ms-word

I am creating an instance of word by calling CreateDispatch("Word.Application"). This works fine except in Vista it causes the dialog about the server being busy to come up and you have to keep hitting the "switch to" button several times. Each time you do it pops up the start menu until it finally opens word. Anybody know why and if there is a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

This happens if your UI thread is waiting for some OLE automation method on a COM server to complete - you could try creating the object in a non-UI thread so that you don't block the UI thread?